# Fix undefined index in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to get the option value from my select txtYear but I get error like undefined index. I don't know what I did wrong?

```
<TR>
    <TH><p style="color:red; width:150px">Year Level</p></TH>
    <TD>
    <SELECT NAME="txtYear" style="width:200px">
            <OPTION VALUE="select any value">
            <OPTION VALUE="First Year">First Year</OPTION>
            <OPTION VALUE="Second Year">Second Year</OPTION>
            <OPTION VALUE="Third Year">Third Year</OPTION>
            <OPTION VALUE="Fourth Year">Fourth Year</OPTION>
            <OPTION VALUE="Fifth Year">Fifth Year</OPTION>
    </SELECT>
    </TD>
</TR>

<TR>
    <TH><p style="color:red; width:150px">Section</p></TH>
     <TD>
<SELECT NAME="txtSec" style="width:200px">
        <OPTION VALUE="select any value">
        <?php
            $year = $_POST['txtYear'];

            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "scheduling");
            if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                {echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();}

            if($year=="First Year"){
                $sql="SELECT `Section` FROM `section` WHERE `Year`='First Year'";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {    
                    echo '<option value="'.$row['Section'].'">'.$row['Section'].'</option>';
                }
            }
        ?>  
</SELECT>
        </TD>
</TR>
```

What happens here is that when a user select first year from combo box year level, it will only display the section based on the year level from the database.

Comment: You can't get `$_POST['txtYear']` until after the user submits the form.

Comment: Is there a `<form>` around this?

Comment: Consider using more machine-readable values like `1` to represent "First year" but keep human-readable labels in the select options. Putting literally `"First Year"` in your database is asking for trouble, as that'll sort very strangely: Fifth, First, Fourth, Second, Third.

Comment: yeah I supposed it has to do with the $_POST, is there a way not to use it because I want to avoid adding another button, user doesn't need to submit the year level value, section part just need to depend on the year level. Isnt it possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. First of All you need a `<form>` around `<select>` tag
2. Add submit button e.g `<input type="submit" name="go">` inside the form
3. Last thing around php code with if statement `if(isset($_POST['go'])){ /** your php code */ }

### Update

Allow me to give you a small advise .. i believe you need ajax request

Comment: I dont want to add another button, what I need to happen is that after user selects from year level option, its value can be read without submitting it? isn;t it not possible?

Comment: @Rin_asdfghjkl - PHP is a sever side language, the client (the browser) happens after the server is finished and all PHP code is ran.  PHP cannot directly interact with user actions.  For this we need JavaScript which runs on the client (the browser).  The server builds the response (ends) and sends HTML source code to client (the browser), where a client can interact with it.  This happens on at least 2 different physical machines (in most cases)

Comment: Like i said brother ,, its just possible with `javaScript` .. specific ajax request to handle it without submit button

Answer (score 0):

You may try to put the `@` before `$_POST['txtYear'];` it will remove the undefined index Notice on **PHP**.

so it will be @$_POST['txtYear'];

---

```
<TR>
    <TH><p style="color:red; width:150px">Year Level</p></TH>
    <TD>
    <SELECT NAME="txtYear" style="width:200px">
            <OPTION VALUE="select any value">
            <OPTION VALUE="First Year">First Year</OPTION>
            <OPTION VALUE="Second Year">Second Year</OPTION>
            <OPTION VALUE="Third Year">Third Year</OPTION>
            <OPTION VALUE="Fourth Year">Fourth Year</OPTION>
            <OPTION VALUE="Fifth Year">Fifth Year</OPTION>
    </SELECT>
    </TD>
</TR>

<TR>
    <TH><p style="color:red; width:150px">Section</p></TH>
     <TD>
<SELECT NAME="txtSec" style="width:200px">
        <OPTION VALUE="select any value">
        <?php
            $year = @$_POST['txtYear'];

            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "scheduling");
            if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                {echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();}

            if($year=="First Year"){
                $sql="SELECT `Section` FROM `section` WHERE `Year`='First Year'";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {    
                    echo '<option value="'.$row['Section'].'">'.$row['Section'].'</option>';
                }
            }
        ?>  
</SELECT>
```

Answer (score 0):

Other users have right! You cannot get $year or  $_POST['txtYear'] until the user has submitted the form (missing in your example)... you can fix as below... you should always check if user has submitted the input data before assuming the data input are ok...

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['txtYear'])) {
      $year = $_POST['txtYear'];
    } else {
      $year = "UNKNOWN";
      // do something in this case...
    }
```

This will fix your undefined index... hope this help.